# Getting ImportError when doing - from pandas import to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a GUI applet that needs to analyze data from many csv files (and also update them).

Right now all that I want is to read the data, update it, and then run `pd.to_csv()` on it.

I did this (first line of the code):

```
from pandas import read_csv, to_csv # because all that I want from pandas are these two things (for now)
```

Getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'to_csv' from 'pandas' (C:\Users\<Your good username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py)
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_csv` is a part of `DataFrame` class. The below example should clear your doubts:

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# list of name, location, pin 
nme = ["John", "Jacky", "Victor"] 
location = ["USA", "INDIA", "UK", "NL"] 
pin = [1120, 10, 770, 1990] 

# dictionary of lists 
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': nme, 'location': location, 'pin': pin})

# saving the dataframe 
df.to_csv('file2.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

It will create a csv file.

Answer (score 3):

`to_csv` is a method of DataFrame class. So you can't import it like you import read_csv because `read_csv` is a function in pandas module but not `to_csv`.

Comment: so I should do this? ```from pandas.DataFrame import to_csv```

Comment: No you have to create a dataFrame object. @CK__ explained it.